# Proper disposal of layers

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, feature-layer, code-review

I have a group layer. Its purpose is to show feature layers over a base map. Those feature layers are logically grouped into categories, and we provide the ability to add/remove whole categories through a menu.

The categorization is done using a dictionary

`layerCategories <string [category name], List<IFeatureLayer>>`

When I want to delete a category, I do something like the following

```
void deleteCategory( string categoryName){
  foreach(var layer in layerCategories[categoryName]){
    theGrouLayer.Delete(layer); // delete layer from group layer
  }
  layerCategories.Remove(categoryName); // remove layers (along with the category)
}
```

The code works but could it be done better i.e. are the layers disposed properly this way or should I do something explicitly?

Comment: Do you just want to remove layers from group layer? For that, I think, your code is perferct